# Multiple OR clauses

Tags: postgresql, elixir, where-clause, ecto

I have a list that I'd like to turn onto a `where` clause using `or`s:

```
my_list = [
  %{min: 1, max: 10},
  %{min: 4, max: 16},
  %{min: 5, max: 21}
]
```

The `where` clause I'm intended to construct is going to be a part of another, bigger query.

Right now I have to write the following code (note the duplication):

```
query =
  my_list
  |> Enum.with_index()
  |> Enum.reduce(bigger_query, fn {item, index}, q ->
       if index == 0 do
         where(q, [table], fragment("? BETWEEN ? AND ?", table.age, ^item["min"], ^item["max"]))
       else
         or_where(q, [table], fragment("? BETWEEN ? AND ?", table.age, ^item["min"], ^item["max"]))
       end
     end)
```

**Can this query be rewritten simpler in Ecto terms?** If yes, how?

**Update**. Consider this example:

```
query = from posts in Post, where: posts.author_id == ^12

query =
  my_list
  |> Enum.with_index()
  |> Enum.reduce(bigger_query, fn {item, index}, q ->
       if index == 0 do
         where(q, [posts], fragment("? BETWEEN ? AND ?", posts.author_age, ^item["min"], ^item["max"]))
       else
         or_where(q, [posts], fragment("? BETWEEN ? AND ?", posts.author_age, ^item["min"], ^item["max"]))
       end
     end)

query = where(q, [posts], posts.published == ^true)
```

The query is generated correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author_id = 12 AND ((age BETWEEN 1 AND 10) OR (age BETWEEN 4 AND 16) AND (age BETWEEN 5 AND 21))
```

**What would be the most compact Ecto code to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the first condition in `where`. `or_where` works just fine even if there are no `where` already in the query. The following should work just fine:

```
query = Enum.reduce(my_list, bigger_query, fn item, q ->
  or_where(q, [table], fragment("? BETWEEN ? AND ?", table.age, ^item["min"], ^item["max"]))
end)
```

You can simplify this further using pattern matching (assuming the keys are strings and you put atoms as keys in the first code snippet in the question by mistake):

```
query = Enum.reduce(my_list, bigger_query, fn %{"min": min, "max": max}, q ->
  or_where(q, [table], fragment("? BETWEEN ? AND ?", table.age, ^min, ^max))
end)
```

Comment: from the [docs to `or_where`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.1.3/Ecto.Query.html#or_where/2): *(it) behaves exactly the same as where except it combines with any previous expression by using an OR*. I'm seeing this exact behavior: if `bigger_query` already has at least a single `where` clause, running `or_where` would `OR` to that already present clause, which is not desired behavior. Instead I need to have `AND (bunch_of_ORs)`

Comment: But then does the longer code you had in the question work correctly?

Comment: `|> where([p], 1 == 1) |> where([p], 2 == 2) |> or_where([p], 3 == 3)` produces this SQL for me: `WHERE ((1 = 1) AND (2 = 2)) OR (3 = 3)` i.e. all the existing `WHERE` are combined and `OR`'d against the first `or_where`.

Comment: your example makes sense, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve. I've updated the question to help us get on the same page. Does the update make sense to you?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's the query generated by that code? Just wanted to confirm because you probably cleaned up that query by hand or wrote it by hand after seeing the actual query in the logs. Your code should be doing `|> where |> where |> or_where |> or_where |> where` assuming you have typos in the code and you meant to use `query` and not `bigger_query` in `Enum.reduce` and `query` and not `q` in the last line.

Comment: If I'm wrong and your code works (`or_where` only picks the last expr), you can always put a `where(0 == 1)` at the start and then use `or_where` in reduce.